# Show umask of user I can't login to

Tags: linux, umask

I know I can show the umask of the current user by simly executing `umask` on the command line.

- Is there any way how I can figure out the umask of a user *I don't have the permissions to login to*? (Also don't have root/sudo access...)

There seems to be some strange configuration somewhere which overrides our system default (i.e. umask of `0022` for UID <200 and `0002` for UID >=200), and I'd love to check what the actual umask of this user is...
(It's a technical user for a web server, so login is not possible...)

Comment: When leaving a down vote please consider also leaving a comment on why you didn't like this question and how it could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

The umask is not an attribute of a user; it belongs to a *process*.  A user may run many processes with different umasks.

On the Unix & Linux stack exchange, someone asked [Is it possible to get current umask of a process?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/258284)  Normally, one would expect such a thing to be exposed in the `/proc` directory of the process, but umask is not exposed anywhere.